# it's not executing the code inside else if(i==1), why is that happening?

Tags: c#, for-loop, if-statement, jagged-arrays

its only executing the code inside of the if(i==0) and ignoring the one inside if(i==1) there is also if(i==2) but i removed due to post restrictions im new to this but if i can figuere out why its not executing the code inside of the first else if statement i might be able to fix fix both

```
 string[][] friendFamily = new string[][]
        {
            new string[]{"khzix","rengar","shaco" },
            new string[]{"jhin","tf","karma" },
            new string[]{"qiyanna","braum","thresh" }
        };
        for (int i = 0; i < friendFamily.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < friendFamily[i].Length; x++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < friendFamily.Length; j++)
                    {
                        if (j == 1 || j == 2)
                        {
                            for (int k = 0; k < friendFamily.Length; k++)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("hey {0} this is {1}.", friendFamily[i][x], friendFamily[j][k]);
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            else if (i == 1)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < friendFamily[i].Length; x++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < friendFamily.Length; j++)
                    {
                        if (j == 0 || j == 2)
                        {
                            for (int k = 0; k < friendFamily.Length; k++)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("hey {0} this is {1}.", friendFamily[i][x], friendFamily[j][k]);
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Not sure why you want to have various conditions like `if(i ==0)` or `if (i == 1)` but I can see code executes for `if (i == 1)`. Check https://dotnetfiddle.net/8sL9aX fiddle

Comment: I run the published pat of code and it work for i==1. You have to publish the whole code to see why it is not working for you. If can't put all trow out i==0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could see that your code works fine, all conditions are met. Actually, I felt pain reading your code. Try to understand what I've done here, it is just what you need:

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;

string[][] friendFamilies = new string[][]
{
    new string[] { "khzix","rengar","shaco" },
    new string[] { "jhin","tf","karma" },
    new string[] { "qiyanna","braum","thresh" }
};

var allFriends = friendFamilies.SelectMany(x => x);

foreach (var friendToGreet in allFriends)
{
    foreach (var friendWhoGreet in allFriends.Where(x => x != friendToGreet))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Hey {friendToGreet} this is {friendWhoGreet}.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works just the way i intended it to, just one more question what should i search to learn more about the code you wrote. Again thanks for the help @IvanKhorin

Comment: You can google for "C# LINQ". Actually it is a set of methods that can be invoked on enumerable variables like arrays or lists. For example you launch .SelectMany() on your "array of arrays" and the result is a one dimentional (flat) array that contains all friends, so allFriends are like `{ "khzix","rengar","shaco", "jhin","tf","karma",  "qiyanna","braum","thresh", }`, then you iterate these friends in foreach one by one.

Comment: Don't think that I blame you for code, but if you use laguage it is better to use all it's benefits. Nobody told me aboud many things and I used additional code that just waste time. "cycle in cycle in cycle..." is not bad for studing but keep in mind that you just waste time eweriwhere you use loop through arrays or lists using indexes, in 99% you can awoid indexes implementing c# possibilities. It makes code much more readable.